# print serialport's listener every 5 results with nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I have a device that connected to the computer via usb cable.
I have access to the data with nodejs via `SerialPort` module.

I Want to get the data online but I want to take data each for each 5 instances.
here is the code and GIT:
https://github.com/eshk12/SerialPort-HTTP-Server/blob/master/routes/index.js

in the first run he print the 5th instance and reset the variable `count` but doesn't proceed again to 5th:

Here is the console:

```
serialport>npm run start

> serialport-test@0.0.0 start D:/serialport
> node ./bin/www

init start
1else
2else
3else
4else
5main
GET /hey 200 652.150 ms - 12
1else
2else
3else
4else
```

`parser.on('data', render);` - this listener keep sending data everytime

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue,
I have take out the `serialport` dependecies from the router and let it run permantly and push the data into variable `lastresult` once some1 access to router `localhost:3000/hey` he will print the results.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors');
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
router.use(cors());

console.log('init start');
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const port = new SerialPort('COM7');
const parser = new Readline();
port.pipe(parser);
var count = 0;
var lastresult = '';
function counter(data){
  if(++count == 5){
    lastresult = data;
    count = 0;
  }
}
parser.on('data', counter);
router.get('/hey', function (req, res) {
  res.send(lastresult);
});
module.exports = router;
```